# Replacment UDID with OpenUDID is this good way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, udid

So apple is rejecting apps which uses UDID. There  are lots of posts on this, but i can't find where is written is it's good to use OpenUDID.

So maybe someone know if apple will approve this ?
If OpenUDID has all features as UDID ?

Maybe someone is using this approach and could explain more ?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the easiest solution is to just generate your own UUID:

```
NSString *UUID() {
    CFUUIDRef cfuuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL); 
    NSString *uuid =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, cfuuid); 
    CFRelease(cfuuid);
    return uuid;
}
```

If you need to keep this across uninstall/install cycles, put it in the keychain as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11597291/382374

Best thing, this is how Apple suggests you do it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We create our own UDIDs based on a hash of the device MAC address and the bundle identifier. This ensures that we can uniquely identify our app on a specific device.

You could also create a hash based only on the MAC address if you need a unique ID across multiple apps.

I've actually written a blog post about how to do this and provided some sample code here:

https://radeeccles.com/blog/create-your-own-unique-device-identifier-udid

Comment: The MAC address will be inaccessible to developers from [iOS 7](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/), so this will be useless in the future

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is good way. Similarly SecureUDID is the one also doing same thing.By Using OpenUDID the UDID is not changing even restart the app or reinstall the application.But if u change any input values like kOpenUDIDDomain or kOpenUDIDSlotPBPrefix then it generates new UDID.Based upon the names it is generating and storing into PasteBoard. If you reset the device also still same.I personally vote for this.