# Uniquely identifying an iOS user

Tags: ios, authentication

I'd like to create a user account on the server for new users of an app, but I'd also like to not ask the user to type in anything. Ideally, I'd like this to be automatic, like with Game Center.

But I'm wondering if it's possible. Is there anything I can use to uniquely identify the user? It's highly unlikely that I can find out the user's Apple ID. Also, the device ID uniquely identifies the device, not the user, so it would be useless if the user has more devices...

Is there anything else I can use?

About privacy - I don't want to find out anything behind the user's back. I have absolutely no problem with asking the user for access to their information (and if there is an API that grants me this information, it would be great if the API asks this itself). As Steve Jobs himself said, this is what privacy is all about - forcing apps to ask the user for permission before doing anything with their private data.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a way.. it would lead to big-time privacy issues.

Comment: @bdares, I don't mind asking for the user's permission... "Can I use your email to log you in?" is much better than "Type in your email and make up a password", especially on an iPhone...

Comment: You can generate a UUID (universally unique identifier), which was very easy to do prior to iOS 5 with some Core Foundation functions, but Apple has now deprecated this, so you can't use this if you are developing for iOS 5+.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not, but how about generating a random user id, saving it to the docs directory, and having it be backed up by iCloud?  This should sync the file to the user's other devices.  Of course this seems very hacky and will only work on newer versions of iOS...

Comment: @borrrden, that sounds like a good idea, but the user may not use iCloud.

Comment: @Radu Then you really have no choice but to get *some* form of input from the user.  Even a password alone will be fine.

Comment: @Radu, is there something about the answer that I provided that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Erik, I don't understand how it could help me, in the case that the user does not use iCloud. I had a similar idea with Game Center, but again, the user might not have a Game Center account. And sending a key from one device to another doesn't sound very good either. Ideally, I'd like to not bother the user and not require any action of him. The way that you get automatically logged in to Game Center is the ideal solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @ Radu, you've got to have someway of connecting a user to multiple devices.  iCloud is the only facility Apple provides to do this.  If you don't want to use iCloud, you have to use the key system.  As an implementation example, Firefox uses the key system for its sync services: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-a-device-to-firefox-sync.  Good luck!

Comment: @Erik, I have no problem using iCloud, but it's possible that the user doesn't have an iCloud account or doesn't use iCloud at all. iCloud is optional. The key system is not ideal, but it's not that bad... However, the user must still have the app. If they remove the app, the account is lost. I would like them to be able to continue using the account even after removing all copies of the app and reinstalling.

Comment: @Radu, if you store your credentials in the Keychain, they will persist through uninstallation/installation cycles.  So if a user re-installs your app, they will be able to reconnect to your service as if they never uninstalled the app.

Comment: @Erik, even so, they might not have the device anymore (given away for getting a better device, etc), or they might re-install the operating system, or they might jailbreak it and break things, etc, so if anything happens to the device, they lose the account. Ideally the server should be able to identify the user somehow. That's what I like about Game Center, that it can easily identify you, but they have the Apple ID they can work with...

Comment: @Radu Can you explain the desired behavior when I use your app, then reset my phone to the factory defaults and sell it to someone else?  Presumably they shouldn't be able to access my account.

Comment: @blahdiblah, indeed they shouldn't, unless of course, they're using your Apple ID.

Comment: Resetting to factory defaults clears the keychain.  You can also have your app clear previous keychain items for your app on first run after installation.  To access the keychain items, the user has to provide Apple ID credentials AND the app has to provide its credentials.

Comment: You can do what Cydia does: link a unique property of each of the user's devices upon first login (I'd suggest getting the MAC address as the UDID is deprecated), then use it as a key.

Comment: @H2CO3, how would I know then it's the same user if they log in from another device?

Comment: @Radu when they log in first from a device, you pair the login info and the device's MAC/UDID.

Comment: @H2CO3, so, on device #1, I get the device identifier, but I don't have any other data about the user, so I can identify him by the device identifier. What do I do now on device #2, with a different device identifier?

Comment: automatic registration of the user on server without user knowing? I would be surprised if doing so is not violating any law.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The correct solution is to use the [iCloud Key-Value Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html), where you can store a unique user ID without requiring any kind of authentication or user information such as an email address.

**The end result is a random UUID (nothing that actually IDENTIFIES the user), that is different for each user, but will persist across multiple devices registered to the same iCloud account.**

We define a field in our iCloud KV Store, let's call it userID. When the app is launched, we first check the userID. If it's there, then we're all set with our user's unique ID. If not, then this is the first time we're running for this user. We generate a random UUID and store it in the KV Store under userID. That's all there is to it.

Our experience shows that this UUID is unique per iTunes account. If your end-users are using family sharing, those accounts will be assigned different UUIDs (which may or may not be desirable but there's nothing you can do about it). Any number of devices launching under the same iTunes account will see the same UUID.

This approach is totally legit and should be approved by Apple with no issues.

**Obviously you must enable iCloud Key-Value store on Xcode under Capabilities, just turn on the iCloud Switch.**

Here's a simple class that implements this concept in Objective-C:

```
@implementation EEUserID

+ (NSUUID *) getUUID
{
    NSUUID *uuid = nil;
    NSString *uuidString = [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] stringForKey: @"EEUserID"];
    if (uuidString == nil)
    {
        // This is our first launch for this iTunes account, so we generate random UUID and store it in iCloud:
        uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
        [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setString: uuid.UUIDString forKey: @"EEUserID"];
        [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString: uuidString];
    }
    
    return uuid;
}

+ (NSString *) getUUIDString
{
    NSUUID *uuid = [self getUUID];
    if (uuid != nil)
        return uuid.UUIDString;
    else
        return nil;
}

+ (void) load
{
    // get changes that might have happened while this
    // instance of your app wasn't running
    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
}

@end
```

And for the header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EEUserID : NSObject

+ (NSUUID *) getUUID;
+ (NSString *) getUUIDString;

@end
```

To use, all you have to do is invoke:

```
NSString *uniqueIDForiTunesAccount = [EEUserID getUUIDString];
```

Enjoy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11687379/188108 says that "in the event of a full iDevice restore, the keychain will be wiped too".  Am I correct that the UUID in the icloud is not affected by this?

Comment: That is correct. This would not be affected by a full device restore because the UUID is not stored in the keychain, it is stored in iCloud. Obviously if the user goes to iCloud and deletes data for your particular app, the UUID would be gone, but a device restore or deleting and then reinstalling your app will not reset this UUID.

Comment: Does this still work? Did you have to account for your app being run on a device that isn't logged into an iCloud account? Looks like maybe the iCloud store part might just fail silently and you would be getting a different UUID on each call?

Comment: For anyone with same question ... from the docs: "If you write to the key-value store object when the user is not signed into an iCloud account, the data is stored locally until the next synchronization opportunity. When the user signs into an iCloud account, the system automatically reconciles your local, on-disk keys and values with those on the iCloud server."

Answer (score 21):

Generate a UUID with this:

```
NSString *UUID() {
    CFUUIDRef cfuuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL); 
    NSString *uuid =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, cfuuid); 
    CFRelease(cfuuid);
    return uuid;
}
```

Nothing here is deprecated or frowned on by Apple -- in fact, it is the way they suggest you do it.  Store the generated UUID in the keychain and it will be there -- even if the user uninstalls and reinstalls your app.  The UUID is unique for the device and the time it was generated.

You can then use various schemes to have the user group their devices together -- iCloud, or some sort of key that you deliver from the server.

Good luck!

**Addition:**

Here's how I store it in the keychain, using the uuid as a username and generating a random password:

```
uuid = UUID();
[keychainItemWrapper setObject:uuid forKey:(__bridge_transfer id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *pass_token = randomString(10);
[keychainItemWrapper setObject:pass_token forKey:(__bridge_transfer id)kSecValueData];
```

Note that all of this can be done without any input from the user.

**Update:**

[MCSMKeychainItem](https://github.com/ObjColumnist/MCSMKeychainItem) has a great solution to UUID generation and storage with `[MCSMApplicationUUIDKeychainItem applicationUUID]`.  The library also has `[MCSMGenericKeychainItem genericKeychainItemWithService:service username:username password:password]`.  Together, these functions take care of everything mentioned above.  Easy to install with [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) too.

Comment: Did you miss this section of the question:  "Also, the device ID uniquely identifies the device, not the user, so it would be useless if the user has more devices..."?

Comment: Did you miss the part where I addressed this with "You can then use various schemes to have the user group their devices together -- iCloud, or some sort of key that you deliver from the server?"

Comment: "various schemes"?  If all you have is a device ID then how can you know which user they are supposed to belong to?

Comment: Two possible ways 1) collect UUIDs in iCloud.  Let iCloud tell you which devices (uuids) are associated with the user (exactly what iCloud is for).  2) Send a short key to the user on one device and have the user enter it on their other device(s).  1) works without user involvement.  2) requires some user involvement.

Comment: Those could work, indeed.  Perhaps a hybrid would be better since I assume the server doesn't care which device is being used.  Back up the first UUID to iCloud and use that to login (create it if it doesn't exist, use it if it does).  I just worry about syncing issues (what if iCloud hasn't synched before the user tries to access the server?).  However, I've seen the light and realize your answer didn't deserve my above comment.

Comment: The iCloud approach is a bit trickier.  If you can deal with just a little user involvement, the short key is the way to go I think.  Peace.

Comment: I have many apps live in app store with different bundle seed ids. How do I make sure to store and access the device id lets say two of my apps running on the same iPad ?

Answer (score 3):

Radu

Excellent question.  We have resolved the issue you describe by integrating Urban Airship (urbanairship.com) into our apps.  Urban Airship offers a grab bag of functionality to support in-app purchases, receipt validation, subscription recovery, content delivery, and Apple Push Notification.

One of the great things about Urban Airship is it's ability to identify a "user", not a device, but a "user" by email address.  It's not really an advertised "feature"... more of a by-product of its intended functionality.

Here is what we have found and how we can leverage Urban Airship to solve the problem you have.

When a user installs your app that has Urban Airship integrated to it, UA somehow generates a UDID-like number, which at the moment, simply identifies the device.

However, if you leverage the subscription recovery components of Urban Airship you can have the user enter an email address.  Once the user enters their email address on the first device... that generated ID becomes their main method of user identification and is associated with that email address.  When they enter their email address on subsequent devices, Urban Airship will trigger an email validation process.  Once the user completes the validation process it updates the ID on the new device to be the same as the ID of the first device and so on. The best part of it is... it's all auto-magic! You simply integrate the components and have the user enter their email address.  You should be able to have it all up and working within an hour.

It also offers functionality to allow the user to change the email address associated with all of their devices.

We have actually implemented and it works VERY well!

NOTE: As of JULY 1st 2013 Urban Airship is deprecating the subscription & recovery functionality

Comment: But this is just what I want to avoid - getting the user to type in their email address (or to type in anything). I would like to be able to identify the user without intervention from him, other than maybe granting the app some sort of permission, which only requires the push of a single big button.

Comment: So your requirement is to associate multiple devices to a single user ID without having the user provide any identification?  You may either have to custom develop something else or tweak something like UA to meet your needs.  Your comment on an above post mentioned you were okay with asking for an email.  It seems like a good fit.  It was for us.  Ultimately we decided typing in a single email address to provide cross platform user identification was an easy trade off.  We haven't had any user resistance to it either.

Comment: Sure, I'm all for custom developing something or tweaking something if that will give the expected result. I never said though that I'm OK with asking for an email. I said that I'm OK with asking if I can use the user's email, provided that the user's permission will give me access to his email... Ideally, I'd like to do something like Game Center, where the user is automatically logged in the application, without any effort on his part.

Comment: Sorry Radu... I misunderstood your response.  Good luck with your solution and sorry I couldn't be of help.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift3/4+**

Using iCloud record ID (CKRecordID). This ID will be unique for iTunes account.

```
let container = CKContainer.default()
container.fetchUserRecordID() {
    recordID, error in

    if let err = error {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
    else if recID = recordID {
        print("fetched ID \(recID.recordName ?? "NA")")
    }
}
```

> For automatically created records, the ID name string is based on a
> UUID and is therefore guaranteed to be unique.

Please note that if device doesn’t have an iCloud account, or has an iCloud account with restricted access, this *returns CKError.Code.notAuthenticated* error

Answer (score 1):

Generating a UUID like Erik suggested is definitely a solid solution. The only (small) caveat might be that in the event of a full iDevice restore, the keychain will be wiped too. The application will generate a new UUID in this scenario and the iDevice cannot be related to an existing user anymore.

Another approach to uniquely identify an iDevice is to generate a unique id based on the MAC address of the network interface and combine it with the app bundle id. This methods yields a unique id that is application specific and durable. It will not change when the iDevice is wiped, restored or when the app is removed and reinstalled. Because of this, there is no need to store this id in the keychain.

Fortunately there are already some people that have created a little library to achieve this. The code can be found on GitHub:

https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

Comment: I don't want to uniquely identify the iDevice. I want to uniquely identify the user.

Comment: I understand your requirement, however with the assumption that it is next to impossible to achieve a unique user identification, this is at the very least a possible alternative to explore.

Comment: That's an excellent approach Bas.  I wonder how long Apple will allow access to MAC addresses though.  Apple deprecated the old UUID to prevent tracking a device across applications -- I suspect they might do the same for the MAC ID eventually too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Erik's suggestion is a third-party library called [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/). You can generate a unique identifier on a per-device basis, and it's dead simple:

```
#include "OpenUDID.h"
NSString* openUDID = [OpenUDID value];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party solutions like [SECUREUDID](http://www.secureudid.org/) also check out [this](http://blog.appsfire.com/appsfire-introduces-the-open-source-openudid-initiative/)

Comment: I already explicitly said several times that this is *not* what I'm looking for. I know how to identify the device. I don't care about identifying the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an absolute sure solution (and only works when iCloud enabled), but it is very easy to implement:
Generate a unique ID once (like UUID) and store it in iCloud key-value-storage.

The only problem is that advanced users know how to delete content from the iCloud.

To prevent the user just editing the unique ID stored in iCloud to someone else ID you can add some kind of secret to.

Answer (score 0):

Today our APP was rejected, becouse of Game Center user identification. It is in App Store Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html .

You can not use uniqe Game Center ID in G: format.

The only way now for us is to use iOS6 Facebook integration.

UPDATE: Our new version with automatic FB logon passed review process and is available on App Store ( Slovni Duel ). Uses also inApp subscription linked to FB profile.

Answer (score -1):

How about using game center and iCloud together to identify user?

It is less likely a user do not play game and do not sync their data.

Comment: You'll get rejected from apple store if you use this for non-game app.